# Multiple align environments for defining a function into a function

Tags: align

I use the amsmath and the diagram.sty from [A](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/diagrams/taylor), but I have nearly no control over the alignment.

```
\begin{align*}
A \colon A &\longrightarrow A \\
X &\longmapsto AAAAAA \\
A &\longmapsto AAA \colon 
{
\begin{diagram}[h=2.5ex,w=4.5ex]\small
AAAA & \longrightarrow & AAAAAA \\
AAA & \longmapsto & AAAAA
\end{diagram}
}
\end{align*}
```

[image: to output something like this]

It is likely that I should not use diagram.sty for that, but I do not find another solution.
In general, the `AAAAAA` "overlaps" with the second function below it

Comment: I don't think the question is answerable in this form (It is not clear what the problem is or what the picture is (it clearly isn't a picture generated by the code fragment). Please always include a complete document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XYn9d.png)?

Answer (score 1):

Use `alignedat` for stating more than two alignment points and nest `aligned` in it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
A \colon A &\rightarrow {} && A \\
X          &\mapsto        && AAAAAA \\
A          &\mapsto        && AAA \colon
  \begin{aligned}[t]
  AAAA & \rightarrow AAAAAA \\
  AAA  & \mapsto  AAAAA
\end{aligned}
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With TABstacks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\setstackgap{S}{8pt}
\begin{document}
\savestack{\tmp}{\alignShortunderstack{
AAAA \rightarrow& AAAAAA \\
  AAA  \mapsto&  AAAAA}}


\alignShortstack{
A \colon A \longrightarrow& A \\
X \longmapsto& AAAAAA \\
A \longmapsto& AAA \colon~ \tmp
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Alternate form:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\setstackgap{S}{8pt}
\begin{document}
\savestack{\tmp}{\alignstackanchor{
AAAA \rightarrow& AAAAAA}{
  AAA  \mapsto&  AAAAA}}


\alignShortstack{
A \colon A \longrightarrow& A \\
X \longmapsto& AAAAAA \\
A \longmapsto& AAA \colon~ \tmp
}
\end{document}
```

[image]